# Create a log of create/delete users in Drupal 7

Tags: hooks, log-messages

I'm creating a log with several actions in drupal.

I register similar actions with hook_watchdog.

```
/**
* Implements hook_watchdog().
*/
function MYMODULE_log_watchdog(array $log_entry) {

  if($log_entry['message']=='Login attempt failed for %user.'){
    my_log_function();
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to detect that is created or deleted a user, and record this information in my custom log.

I'm new in drupal development and I Appreciate any guidance to investigate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could actually log the details about user creation at [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7)(), and deletion using [hook_user_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7)().

User creation: Acts on new user creation

```
function MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  watchdog('user', 'User created with ID: %userid', array('%userid' => $account->uid]), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL);
}
```

User deletion: Acts on account deletion

```
function MODULE_user_delete($account) {
  watchdog('user', 'User having ID: %userid deleted', array('%userid' => $account->uid]), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind, the user module already creates watchdog log entries when a user is created or deleted:

### User created

```
watchdog('user', 'New user: %name (%email).', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'], '%email' => $form_state['values']['mail']), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('edit'), 'user/' . $account->uid . '/edit'));
```

in [user_register_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_register_submit/7)

### User deleted

```
watchdog('user', 'Deleted user: %name %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => '<' . $account->mail . '>'), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
```

in [_user_cancel](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_cancel/7)

### Other user watchdog calls ( filename:line-number)

```
./user.pages.inc:81:    watchdog('user', 'Password reset instructions mailed to %name at %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail));
./user.pages.inc:131:          watchdog('user', 'User %name used one-time login link at time %timestamp.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%timestamp' => $timestamp));
./user.pages.inc:171:  watchdog('user', 'Session closed for %name.', array('%name' => $user->name));
./user.pages.inc:450:    watchdog('user', 'Sent account cancellation request to %name %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => '<' . $account->mail . '>'), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
./user.admin.inc:355:      watchdog('file system', 'The directory %directory does not exist or is not writable.', array('%directory' => $picture_path), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
./user.module:616:    watchdog_exception('user', $e);
./user.module:2174:      watchdog('user', 'Login attempt failed for %user.', array('%user' => $form_state['values']['name']));
./user.module:2223:  watchdog('user', 'Session opened for %name.', array('%name' => $user->name));
./user.module:2368:    watchdog('user', 'Attempted to cancel non-existing user account: %id.', array('%id' => $uid), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
./user.module:2419:      watchdog('user', 'Blocked user: %name %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => '<' . $account->mail . '>'), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
./user.module:2430:      watchdog('user', 'Deleted user: %name %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => '<' . $account->mail . '>'), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
./user.module:2485:      watchdog_exception('user', $e);
./user.module:3145:        watchdog('security', 'Detected malicious attempt to alter protected user fields.', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
./user.module:3641:  watchdog('action', 'Blocked user %name.', array('%name' => $account->name));
./user.module:3807:  watchdog('user', 'New user: %name (%email).', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'], '%email' => $form_state['values']['mail']), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('edit'), 'user/' . $account->uid . '/edit'));
```

An alternative approach would be to look into the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module which can intercept various events, such as a watchdog entry, and perform an action, such as emailing someone - all configured via the user interface with export/import functionality and a good API.

Rules can act on the following user events out of the box:

- After a user account has been deleted
- After saving a new user account
- After updating an existing user account
- Before saving a user account
- User account page is viewed
- User has logged in
- User has logged out

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about the module [Role Watchdog](http://drupal.org/project/role_watchdog)!  It will log user delete / user create for you via an entry that shows the 'authenticated user' role being added/removed in concert with the user addition / removal.  It also works with og, and is more persistent than the watchdog messages (presuming that you periodically flush your watchdog cache, as most do).